# Tkinter radiobutton implementation

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

My first ever question in here. To the point. I want to implement an interface with tkinter containing multiple groups of radio buttons. Every group will have three radio buttons (Good, Normal, Bad). After the code execution the user will choose the radio buttons he wants and at the end he presses a button to collect the values of all radio buttons so we could have a statistic view of how many, let's say "Good", have been selected. All the above should be implemented as much dynamically as it is possible.

The things i tried.
I used generators for the:

1. Rows of the labels.
2. Rows of the radio buttons.
3. Names that the variable=var should take.

Here's the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

my_list = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]

# Set up all the components of the UI.
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Radio Buttons Test')
root.geometry("1024x768")

# Create counters for use in placing radio buttons.
# Generic counter for labels or wherever it might be useful.
def counter(listfile):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        if i != 0:
            yield i
            i +=1
count = counter(my_list)

#Counter for rows with even numbers.
def even_counter(listfile):
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 2 + 1):
        if i != 0 and i % 2 == 0:
            yield i
even = even_counter(my_list)

#Counter for rows with odd numbers.
def odd_counter(listfile):
    odd_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        if i > 2 and i % 2 != 0:
            odd_numbers.append(i)
    odd_lst = odd_numbers * 4
    odd_lst.sort()
    for x in odd_lst:
        yield x
odd = odd_counter(my_list)

# Generating numbers to be used in radiobutton's variable naming.
def var_values(listfile):
    var_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        var_numbers.append(i)
    var_lst = var_numbers * 3
    var_lst.sort()
    for x in var_lst:
        yield x
rb_var_values = var_values(my_list)


def labels(listfile):
    for i in listfile:
        label_text = tk.Label(root, text=str(next(count))+ '. ' + i, font=("Arial", 11))
        label_text.grid(column=0, row=next(even), sticky="w", columnspan=3)

# Generate radio buttons.
rblst = []
var_value = 0
def radio_buttons(listfile):
    global var
    for rb in range(len(listfile)):
        var = tk.IntVar(None)
        var_value = next(rb_var_values)
        var.set(var_value)
        rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Good", variable=var, value=1)
        rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Normal", variable=var, value=2)
        rb3 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Bad", variable=var, value=3)
        rblst.extend([rb1,rb2,rb3])
        comment = tk.Entry(root, width=60, borderwidth=3)
        rb1.grid(column=0, row=next(odd))
        rb2.grid(column=1, row=next(odd))
        rb3.grid(column=2, row=next(odd))
        comment.grid(column=3, row=next(odd), pady=5)

# Function for the command of "Stats" button.
def stat_btn():
    for i in rblst:
        print(f'ID is: {id(i)} and Variable is {var.get()}')
    print('Length is',len(rblst))

# Create and place the "Stats" button.
bt = tk.Button(root, text="Stats", command=stat_btn)
bt.grid(column=5,row=47, sticky="se")

labels(my_list)
var_values(my_list)
radio_buttons(my_list)
root.mainloop()
```

By pressing the Stats button i get wrong results, meaning that only the last group of radio buttons affects the result of var.getand not the first and the second group. You think it's the variable or the value of the radio buttons that cause this problem? Will OOP implementation of the above code will make things easier to manage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement like this, You can copy this code and i hope this works.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

my_list = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Radio Buttons Test')
root.geometry("1024x768")

def counter(listfile):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        if i != 0:
            yield i
            i +=1

count = counter(my_list)

def even_counter(listfile):
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 2 + 1):
        if i != 0 and i % 2 == 0:
            yield i

even = even_counter(my_list)

def odd_counter(listfile):
    odd_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        if i > 2 and i % 2 != 0:
            odd_numbers.append(i)
    odd_lst = odd_numbers * 4
    odd_lst.sort()
    for x in odd_lst:
        yield x

odd = odd_counter(my_list)

def var_values(listfile):
    var_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(listfile) * 3 + 1):
        var_numbers.append(i)
    var_lst = var_numbers * 3
    var_lst.sort()
    for x in var_lst:
        yield x

rb_var_values = var_values(my_list)

def labels(listfile):
    for i in listfile:
        label_text = tk.Label(root, text=str(next(count))+ '. ' + i, font=("Arial", 11))
        label_text.grid(column=0, row=next(even), sticky="w", columnspan=3)

rblst = []
var_values_list = []  # List to hold the var variables for each group

def radio_buttons(listfile):
    global var
    for rb in range(len(listfile)):
        var = tk.IntVar(None)
        var_value = next(rb_var_values)
        var.set(var_value)
        rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Good", variable=var, value=1)
        rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Normal", variable=var, value=2)
        rb3 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Bad", variable=var, value=3)
        rblst.extend([rb1, rb2, rb3])
        comment = tk.Entry(root, width=60, borderwidth=3)
        rb1.grid(column=0, row=next(odd))
        rb2.grid(column=1, row=next(odd))
        rb3.grid(column=2, row=next(odd))
        comment.grid(column=3, row=next(odd), pady=5)
        var_values_list.append(var)  # Store the var variable for each group

def stat_btn():
    for i, var in enumerate(var_values_list):
        print(f'ID is: {id(rblst[i])} and Variable is {var.get()}')
    print('Length is', len(rblst))

bt = tk.Button(root, text="Stats", command=stat_btn)
bt.grid(column=5, row=47, sticky="se")

labels(my_list)
var_values(my_list)
radio_buttons(my_list)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works! I got stuck on this for two weeks... My fault was that i didn't collect the "var" values in a list so i could access them again later. Glad for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).